# How do I get a toolbar for the Silverlight 4 RichTextBox?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I put the RichTextBox in my Silverlight App. Do I have to create my own set of buttons to use it? I want to have a standard set of editing buttons for the text box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's just the textbox not a whole suite of controls too like the toolbar, which is something you get with commercial WPF/Silverlight rich text boxes.

You tie your buttons up to format code [as shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613(VS.96).aspx#formatting_text_at_run_time):

```
//Set Bold formatting to selected content
private void BtnBold_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object o = MyRTB.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);
    if (o.ToString() != "Bold")
        MyRTB.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);


}
//<SnippetItalic>
//Set Italic formatting to selected content
private void BtnItalic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object o = MyRTB.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);
    if (o.ToString() != "Italic")
        MyRTB.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic);


}

//Set Underline formatting to selected content
private void BtnUnderline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object o = MyRTB.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);
    if (o.ToString() != "Underline")
        MyRTB.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
}
```

Comment: this is good solution that can be completed with this control http://wintoolbar.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

To give your Silverlight app a formatting toolbar with a Mircosoft Office-style feel, check out the [MSDN Silverlight Text Editor example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)